# How do I count unread comments using "Unread" Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

*comments_helper.rb*:

```
module CommentsHelper
  def unread_comments_count
    @comments_count = Comment.unread_by(user).count
  end
end
```

In my `ApplicationController`, I defined `user`:

```
def user
  @user = User.find_by(params[:user_id])
end
```

I could have used `current_user`, but the result I got (with that) is total number of comments in my database. So, I thought I should use `user`. But it didn't work.

*view*:

```
<%= unread_comments_count %>
```

However, the result is still total number of all the comments made on all the posts by all users. I can't actually figure out what I am doing wrong because I have carefully done everything right in my Models as guided by the gem.

I would appreciate any clue to fix this.

**Update**

The query it generates is:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" 'LEFT JOIN read_marks ON read_marks.readable_type = "Message" AND read_marks.readable_id = comments.id AND read_marks.reader_id = 1 AND read_marks.reader_type = 'User' AND read_marks.timestamp >= comments.created_at WHERE read_marks.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Try running the same thing `Comment.unread_by(user).count` in `rails console`. See if it gives the expected output.

Comment: It doesnt return anything... I am kinda thinking there is something i havent added to my database that wasnt added during unread gem generated some migration files...

Comment: Could there be any gem you have used in the past or any working online source i can use to just track total number of unread comments made on a post belonging to a current_user?

Comment: _"It doesnt return anything."_ - you can check the database query it fires.

Comment: FROM Comments
'LEFT JOIN read_marks ON read_marks.readable_type = "Message"
                    AND read_marks.readable_id = comments.id
                    AND read_marks.reader_id = 1
                    AND read_marks.reader_type = 'User'
                    AND read_marks.timestamp >= messages.created_at
WHERE read_marks.id IS NULL

Comment: From https://github.com/ledermann/unread it suppose to have at the end
 AND messages.created_at > '2010-10-20 08:50:00'
Mine is not generating that query